# How to Save all photos together from e-mail when using Inbox app?

Tags: email, photos, iphone

I am using iPhone 6+ with iOS 9 version. Have installed 'Inbox' (by G-mail, not the old G-mail app).  Is there any way to save all of the pictures from an email, no matter how long it take to download?

Thanks a lot for your time to answer.

John

Answer (score 1):

Don't know about Inbox, but in Mail app there's a button within the `share` options that allows you to do just what you want.